# Calculate string width (in pixels) in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have a Label with very-very long string in it.

`Method label.getOffsetWidth()` returns 0 (I dont know why). But `String` is displayed.

How can i get Label (or String) width in pixels using `GWT 2.4.0`?

Comment: Do you want the width in pixels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found answer for my question.
For be sure that Label have rendered use [Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29)([Scheduler.ScheduledCommand](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.ScheduledCommand.html) cmd)

In `@Override execute()`
call `label.getElement().getClientWidth();`

And that's it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ***getClientWidth()*** method of underlying DOM element to get its width in pixels:

```
label.getElement().getClientWidth();
```

[see](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getClientWidth%28%29)

Comment: strange behavior. It returns 0.

Comment: @user1081538: make sure you call this method after element is rendered

Comment: Thanks, it's really important thing